# How do you write a regex replace in notepad++ replacing echo 'text' with echo "text"?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to do a regex in notepad++ to replace all my `echo 'random text'` with `echo "random text"` but I can't figure out what to write for the replace.

I have this in the find `echo '.*'` but I don't know what to put for the echo "random text" in the replace box.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a pattern like this:

```
^(\s*echo\s*)'([^']*)'
```

And a replacement pattern like this:

```
$1"$2"
```

Make sure you have the various modes set up correctly:

[image: full details]

Comment: This is more like I was going to suggest. The `[^']` part means match everything except the quote character

Answer (score 4):

While been easy, what's the point of doing that? oh well this is how to do it:

find - `echo '(.*?)'`

replace - `echo "\1"`

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was going to post. Tested in Notepad++, works 100%.

Comment: Maybe use the [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) form of * to ensure you do not replace too much. So find `echo '(.*?)'` instead of `echo '(.*)'`.

Comment: You'd better use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replace part.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if notepad++ supports the full regular expression set, but replacing

```
echo '*([^']*)'
```

(note the blank between `echo` and `*`)

with

```
echo "\1"
```

should work. If it doesn't, use

```
echo '*\([^']*\)'
```

instead for the search string.

Comment: I used a '{blank}*' instead of just a '{blank}' in case you have more than one space character between the `echo` and the string somewhere.